# How to make full backup of Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, backup, office365, sharepoint-online

Is there any way to make a **full backup** of Sharepoint Online web site based on Office 365 without third-party tools? Tried to google it, but found only ways to manually backup list or libraries. I'm need to save user properties, permissions, webparts, etc.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is SharePoint online, you won't be able to perform a full-backup as you'd be able to do with Backup-SPSite.

However, you can save your site as a template. If your publishing feature is enabled for this site, you'll need to enable saving the website as a template via SharePoint Designer. Under the "Site" tab, select “Site Options”, find "SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled" and set to "true". Then 
add this to your site's url:

/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx

Fill out and submit the form. In my experience, that should take about 10 minutes, or the working on it screen might never change. If the later happens, you can check for your solution on this page:

/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx

This option might not work if your site is over 50MB, so you might need to forgo checking the option that allows including your list content in this backup.